# reservoir sampling understanding probaility

Tags: algorithm, random, probability, probability-theory, reservoir-sampling

I am having trouble understanding the probabilities involved in reservoir sampling. Below is the sample code which I have seen used in almost everywhere:

```
    1/*
    2  S has items to sample, R will contain the result, K number of items to select
    3*/
    4ReservoirSample(S[1..n], R[1..k])
    5  // fill the reservoir array
    6  for i = 1 to k
    7      R[i] := S[i]
    8
    9 // replace elements with gradually decreasing probability
    10  for i = k+1 to n
    11    j := random(1, i)   // important: inclusive range
    12    if j <= k
    13        R[j] := S[i]
```

Is my understanding right(?):
Suppose we have k=3 and input = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500] and i is currently at 500 index. Probability of 500 replacing 300 in the reservoir(which is 3 in size) = probability of 300 being selected in the reservoir * probability of 500 being selected which is only possible if the index returned by random function is less than or equal to 3 out of 5 choices = 1/3 * 3/5 = 1/5

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: ok? I went through that link and this code is from there but I just wanted to check my understanding of that material.

Answer (score -1):

Your understanding doesn't seem to be correct. The probability of 500 getting selected is nowhere related to the selection of 300.

You should check out the [gfg link for the same.](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reservoir-sampling/) "How does this work?" section, which states the following:

> Case 1: For last n-k stream items, i.e., for stream[i] where k <= i < n 
>   For every such stream item stream[i], we pick a random index from 0 to i and if the picked index is one of the first k indexes, we replace the element at picked index with stream[i]
>
> To simplify the proof, let us first consider the last item. The probability that the last item is in final reservoir = The probability that one of the first k indexes is picked for last item = k/n (the probability of picking one of the k items from a list of size n)
>
> Let us now consider the second last item. The probability that the second last item is in final reservoir[] = [Probability that one of the first k indexes is picked in iteration for stream[n-2]] X [Probability that the index picked in iteration for stream[n-1] is not same as index picked for stream[n-2] ] = [k/(n-1)]*[(n-1)/n] = k/n.
>
> Similarly, we can consider other items for all stream items from stream[n-1] to stream[k] and generalize the proof.
>
> Case 2: For first k stream items, i.e., for stream[i] where 0 <= i < k 
>   The first k items are initially copied to reservoir[] and may be removed later in iterations for stream[k] to stream[n].
>   The probability that an item from stream[0..k-1] is in final array = Probability that the item is not picked when items stream[k], stream[k+1], …. stream[n-1] are considered = [k/(k+1)] x [(k+1)/(k+2)] x [(k+2)/(k+3)] x … x [(n-1)/n] = k/n